# SWF doesn't show up

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3, xhtml, flash-cs5

I don't have a clue on what I'm doing wrong. Sometimes, when I open this page my html page , the swf don't appear. It won't happen always, but is really frequent.

Important: when it don't appear, **I do can hear the sounds that the swf movie makes**. In other words, I'm shure that the object is on the page, but it just won't be visualizable.

The error occurs on **Firefox and Chrome** (I didn't see it happening with IE, but I won't doubt that it is possible)

The problem **isn't in the swf** because I have already tested with another file that have no code at all and the same problem occurs.

Here is the page's code, generated by Flash CS5.5 when publishing the swf:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hellbound</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #000000">
        <div id="flashContent">
            <p align="center">
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="640" height="500" id="Hellbound" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="Hellbound_secure.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="gpu" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Hellbound_secure.swf" width="640" height="500">
                    <param name="movie" value="Hellbound_secure.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="gpu" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific than "sometimes"? Where is the page, what are you loading there, is there any error messages or traces in debug player?

Comment: the page is exactly what I put on the question. I'm trying to load a swf to be shown on the page. 'Sometimes' means sometimes. Not always nor never

Comment: Maybe it is more to do with what is happening in the swf, rather than the embedding. Are you loading the page locally or on a server? Can you try run the page with flash debug player installed and, for instance, include some traces in your swf at crucial points, to identify until what points your swf is working (as you can hear sounds, it is loading)

Comment: +1 ill be looking @ this one for replies/results, i too have a site where this news ticker in flash doesnt show up...but not always...weird

Comment: I agree with @kontur that it's likely to be something going on with the swf, not the embed code.  The embed code looks solid to me.  Are you able to post AS from the flash file?

Comment: What browser do you use and which version?

Comment: It's not about the swf because the same error occurs with other files that have no code at all. I tested with Chrome and Firefox and both had the same issue.

Comment: What kind of player versions are you publishing for and what kind of player versions are you running in the browsers that you experience the errors? Try installing the Flash debug player (http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) and see if you get any particular messages when the video fails to load.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's tempting to use the embed code generated by the Flash authoring tool's Publish feature, but I've had much better luck with one of the javascript replacement methods.  I'd look at SWFobject.  It seems to be the most dependable embedding routine and it's pretty easy to use.  ...plus, it does a good job of handling the foibles of the various browsers.

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: While the embed code generated by flash used to be a horrible mix of scripts and markup, I have personally made only good experiences with the code generated by Flash CS5 upwards. This is not so say using swfobject might not be helping this problem, but just a comment on your advice.